# How to merge block in YML file with |

Tags: merge, yaml

As example, I have next yml file:

```
SectionA: |
  some text
  with new line struct

SectionB: |
 some text
 with additionals
```

I need to merge SectionA text into SectionB, something like this, but it does not work:

```
SectionA: &section_a |
  some text
  with new line struct

SectionB:
  <<: * section_a 
  |
  some text
  with additionals
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible +)
Need to use other format or yaml structure.